# problem with exe widgets not visible in top-level tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, python-3.10

I am using python 3.10 and `pyinstaller` with auto-py-to-exe
When I run the exe without problem the main window is displayed and when I validate the password a new window with `TopLavel` is executed, if it is executed but empty in which I really have `frames, entrys, labels, images` etc.
from visual code it runs perfectly saving values in database but at the time of making and executing the exe does not appear any widget in `TopLavel`.
HELP PLEASE...

This is the main window and it runs without any problem in the .exe

[image]

And this is the one that should appear after validating the password, this is executed from `VsCode`

[image]

However it appears like this in the .exe, the widgets are not visible

[image]

Comment: This usually happens when it hits an error and further code is no longer executed. To see the error, you have to make the exe run with console

Comment: share top level window code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.